# How to determine if a point lies within a kml or shape

Tags: google-maps, kml, point, google-fusion-tables

I have some shape data (a series of kml files in the column of a fusion table and or database) and I want to merg it with another table that contains latitude longitude points. Basically I want some way of determining if a given lat lon point is contained within on of the kml shapes, and if so save a reference to that row.
     I though perhaps there was a way to do this from within fusion tables, but if not, perhaps there is a way to loop through each kml and test if the lat lon point is contained within it. I understand this in not terribly efficient.
     Any help, algorithm, service etc would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Fusion Tables SQL API has a ST_INTERSECTS operator but will only find points within either a CIRCLE or a RECTANGLE.  GMap V3 has a geometry library which has a poly.containsLocation() method which I think will work for arbitrary polygons.  See: [GoogleMap geometry/poly library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#poly)

P.S. I realize this does not work for KML files, but they do contain the polygon points which could be turned into GMAP polygons

Comment: Splendid, that's a great start

Answer (score 0):

This is probably long since solved, but as I had a similar problem I thought I'd post my solution.

I had two Fusion tables i) address & data and ii) polygons & data.  I wanted to be able to easily query to find all addresses within one or more of the polygons.  I could have done this realtime via my mapping webpage, but decided it was better to lookup the relevant polygon once in advance and then use this data to do my mapping queries (faster and easier to specify multiple polygons in the web interface).

So, I exported my table i) with the addresses to google sheets, and created a short simple script that checked which polygon the address was in and wrote it back to the google sheet.  Then I updated my fusion table i).

I had a data set of nearly 3000 addresses and 2000 polygons so it timed out a few times and a had a couple of address errors, but this was easy to fix and I just set the script to run from the first row that hadn't been updated.  Note that this won't work if the polygons overlap each other, but mine didn't as they were geographic boundaries ;-)

The code I used is below and also on gist [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b059242c9aa5e131567c105c6681c19c).  You obviously need to update the table ID, and probably need to do something with OAuth (which I didn't quite understand but followed google's instructions and got it done).

```js
// replace with your fusion table's id (from File > About this table)
var TABLE_ID = 'xxxxxxxxxx';

// first row that has data, as opposed to header information
var FIRST_DATA_ROW = 2;
var FIRST_DATA_COLUMN = 11;
var LAT_COLUMN = 1;
var LNG_COLUMN = 2;
var SA2_COLUMN = 6;
var SA3_COLUMN = 7;

/**
 * Uses a lat and lng data in google sheets to check if an address is within a kml polygon 
 * in a list of KML polygons in fusion (in this case ABS/ASGC SA2 and SA3 regions, but could be any polygon) 
 * the function then stores the ID/name of the relevant polygon in google sheets 
 * I could check this data in realtime as I render maps, but as it doesn't changed, figure its better to just record
 * which polygon each address pertains to so its quicker and easier to search (in particular it mades it easier to write a query
 * which identifies all the address within multiple polygons)
 * in this case I had 3000 rows so it exceeded maximum execution times, so I just updated the first data row a couple of times
 * when the execution time exceeded.
 */
function updateSA2ID() {
  var tasks = FusionTables.Task.list(TABLE_ID);  
  var sqlResponse = '';
  
  // Only run if there are no outstanding deletions or schema changes.
  if (tasks.totalItems === 0) {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var latLngData = sheet.getRange(FIRST_DATA_ROW, FIRST_DATA_COLUMN, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn());
    
      i = 1;
    // Loop through the current current sheet
    for (i = 1; i <= latLngData.getNumRows(); i++) {      
      
      // cross reference to Fusion table
      lat = latLngData.getCell(i,LAT_COLUMN).getValue();
      lng = latLngData.getCell(i,LNG_COLUMN).getValue();
            
      sqlString = "SELECT 'SA2 Code', 'SA3 Code'  FROM " + TABLE_ID + " WHERE ST_INTERSECTS(geometry, CIRCLE(LATLNG(" + lat + ", " + lng + "),1)) ";      
      //Browser.msgBox('Lat ' + lat + ' Lng ' + lng + '; ' + sqlString, Browser.Buttons.OK);
      sqlResponse = FusionTables.Query.sql(sqlString);
      //Browser.msgBox('SQL Response ' + sqlResponse, Browser.Buttons.OK);

      latLngData.getCell(i,SA2_COLUMN).setValue(sqlResponse.rows[0][0]); // set SA2
      latLngData.getCell(i,SA3_COLUMN).setValue(sqlResponse.rows[0][1]); // set SA3     

    }
      
  } 
  else {
    Logger.log('Skipping row replacement because of ' + tasks.totalItems + ' active background task(s)');
  }
};
```